# loading Semicolon separated values to mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

I've values in a csv file like below
2017-05-01 00:00:04.651;Mother Telecommunication;Unique Infoway ltd;GP;01759257722;00966570053415;SAUDI ARABIA;Saudi Arabia-Al Jawwal GSM Network-mobile;9665;0.02;15;1;4;3.06;0.94;0.141;3.201
at a row.

I want to load it to mysql using 
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/html/processed_mysql_csv/xyz_details_report_20170810190128.csv' 
INTO TABLE GP_UIL_BILL_RECON 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

but all the values stored only in first column.

What can I do to place values to their related columns

Comment: is there any way we can get more than one sample row of data. I can't see anything wrong with your line that's obvious but maybe more data would help us identify and help you with the issue.

Comment: Your fields are not `ENCLOSED BY '"'` (which means your first field does not end). Remove that part completely, use `''` or add `optionally`.